# Example on compactness

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Is there any example of a set in a metric space that is closed and bounded but it's not reducible to a finite subcover?

I know that the Heine Borel theorem states that the latter is true for $\mathbb{R}^p$, but I also know that it isn't true for more general metric spaces.

Comment: I think you mean you want the property "Every open cover has a finite subcover" to fail. You can read on wikipedia here (one example,  suggested there, is the set of rational numbers in the interval $[0,1]$, particularly because the metric space of rationals is not "complete"): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem

Comment: Yes!, I mean that, I'm sorry. I saw the example, it was very straightforward. Thanks a lot!